# Faster Alternative to Iterrows() while looping through dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find an alternative to looping through a dataframe from a list of given column and replacing all the 'nan' which specific values that i want. Right now I'm using iterrows which is super slow, is there an alternative to this?

Basically what I have is some columns with NAN values, these columns should only contain 1s or 0s. So what I to do is replace the NAN in each row by the percentage of 1s and 0s that already existed in each column. Lets say column_T has 30% 1s and 70% 0s, so for every iteration i want to pass it through a randint() condition, and if it less than the 30% threshold it would input in 1 for that particular row and vice versa for 0 this would continue for every existing row of NAN.

Example Df.

| Column_T | Column_I |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| nan | nan |
| 1 | 0 |
| nan | 0 |
| 0 | nan |
| 1 | 1 |

```
for i, row in target_df.iterrows():
                for j in missing_col_list:
                    num_missing_obs = target_df[j].value_counts().sort_index()
                    chance_for_0s = (num_missing_obs[0]/(num_missing_obs[1]+num_missing_obs[0]))*100
                
                    #random assign 1s and 0s for missing data by calculated chance
                    if(str(row[j]) == 'nan'):
                        if (random.randint(0,100) < chance_for_0s): 
                            target_df.at[i,j] = 0.0
                        else:
                            target_df.at[i,j] = 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach using [`pandas.Series.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html):

```
for col in df.columns:
    isnan = df[col].isna()
    df.loc[isnan, col] = df[col].dropna().sample(isnan.sum()).values
```

Comment: how would i include an if condition based on the percentage of 1s and 0s???

Comment: @DavidLe I took advantage of the method `sample` since it will return 1s and 0s based on the original proportions

Comment: @DavidLe I mean, I'm trusting in probabilities so I don't need an if